# How to retrieve data from database depending on parameters from form in Joomla?

Tags: php, database, forms, joomla

I have the next task with my Joomla site:
I have events stored in DB. Depending on parameters user chose in form (from date, till date, type of event etc.), I need to get proper events form databse to display in table. And I have no idea, how to realize it all: form, interaction with DB based on form data, displaying the results on new page.

Comment: It should be a very very long answer. First of all - what skills in html, Joomla and php do you have? Where do you want this form to be displayed? I'd suggest you to start from building a html form with all parameters needed to filter data in database.

Comment: There is a link to page with form in sidebar menu. To build form using html is not a problem. I don't understand what to do next.
I have normal skills in HTML, used a little Joomla and didn't try php.

Comment: Well it will be very tricky to explain, if you don't have knowledge in php. But basically what you need to to is: 1. Create you own blank Joomla component, 2. Make sure that your html form's action leads to your components controller; 3. Use your component to retrieve form data, build sql query and output results;